# How do I increase the number of points in a live updating spline chart?

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I have a chart like this, you can see that only about 22 points in the chart from left to right. I want to increase this, so that there are more points. Right now it seems very jumpy, but the range is only between 10-11.5, I want to "zoom out" so the line almost looks flat, and these huge peaks and valleys look like little bumps. I've combed over the highcharts documentation and cannot find this config setting.

Answer (score 0):

In the initial creation of the spline chart, an array of point is created, in the default case it is 49 samples, here I changed it to 200, which did what I needed.

```
series: [{
  name: 'Random data',
  data: (function () {
    // generate an array of random data
    var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

    for (i = -200; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        data.push({
            x: time + i * 1000,
            y: Math.random()
        });
    }
    return data;
  }())
}]
```